# Is there any way to update the scope variable in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I was using the protractor test, I am curious if protractor has a function to update the scope variable.

for Insance:

select the element:

```
var radio=element(by.model('radiobutton'));
radio.value=undefined;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate

```
var radio=element(by.model('radiobutton'));
radio.evaluate('value = undefined')
```

evaluate accepts string parameter - script that you want to evaluate in current element scope.